# How to find a point on a triangle with a given length

Tags: math, geometry

Given are 2 legs of a polyline defined by P1-P2-P3. On the 2nd leg (P2-P3) a point F is defined. How I can get the coordinates of a point R on the 1st leg (P1-P2) if the distance cl (F-R) is known?

Comment: You should probably post this in [Math](http://math.stackexchange.com/) instead of here.

Comment: You haven't enough information to do this (if my understanding is correct).

Comment: He can do it with the information given. But there might be more than one solution.

Comment: would you not need to know the P2 angle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you know the coordinates of the points P1(X1,Y1), P2(X2,Y2), F(Xf,Yf) and the distance cl between F and R:

The point R must satisfy the equations

```
(Xf-x)^2+(Yf-y)^2=cl^2
```

and

```
((Y1-Y2)/(X1-X2))*x=y
```

What you now need to do is finding the intersection of the circle (first equation) and the line (second equation). See [this](http://www.vitutor.com/geometry/conics/circle-line.html) for example how to do this.

Comment: It doesn't need to be a right-angled triangle. Imagine that you draw a circle with radius cl around the given point F (first equation). The leg P1-P2 is a line (second equation). All points that fulfill both equations (1 or 2 points) are intersections.